# Rspec - include other folders specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a Rails project, in which I have a library with specs, `lib/foo`, which contains a `spec` folder:

```
Rails.root
  /lib
    /foo
      /lib
      /spec
```

When I run `rspec` in Rails root, I would like the `foo` specs to be ran too. How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run it like that: `rspec spec/ lib/foo/spec`